# How printf("%c\n",~('C'*-1)) is computed in c?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("%c\n",~('C'*-1));
return 0;
}
```

I have tried the above source code and executed without any warnings.

The output is **B**.
I am excited how the above code is processed and what is the meaning for printf("%c\n",~('C'*-1))

Comment: Cool. Two's complement vs. ones complement.

Comment: That would sooo not pass a code review.

Comment: It depends on the reviewers and their state of mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, `'C'` is an `int`, it's a small integer with a value of `67` (assuming ASCII). You can get each step from:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", 'C');            //67
    printf("%d\n", 'C' * -1);       //-67
    printf("%d\n", ~('C' * - 1));   //66
    printf("%c\n",~('C' * -1));     //B
    return 0;
}
```

In 2's complement, the value of `~(-67)` is `66`.

Comment: On a two's complement processor.

Answer (score 5):

The only important part is this expression:

```
~('C' * -1)
```

Let's break it down:

- `'C'` is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) code 67.
- `('C' * -1)` is -67.
- -67 is, in binary, 10111101
- Bitwise negate that (with `~`), and you have 01000010, which is 66.
- 66 is the ASCII code for 'B'.

More generally, most computers use "[two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)" arithmetic, where numerical negation followed by bitwise negation is equivalent to subtracting 1.  And of course `B` is one less than `C` in ASCII.

On a computer that doesn't use two's complement arithmetic, the result may be different.  Such computers are rare.

Comment: "-67 is, in binary, 10111101" would have a minimum of 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that "making a number negative" (multiplying it by `-1`) in two's complement is equivalent to inverting its bit-representation (`~`) and adding one (`+1`). Thus the above is equivalent to `~(~'C' + 1)`, which in turn is equivalent to a simple decrement if the original number, like here the ASCII-Code of `'C'`, was odd.

That is, if the LSB of `'C'` is set:

- The LSB of `~'C'` isn't set, which means that
- after adding one (`~'C' + 1`) the LSB is set again.
- Inverting the whole expression now (`~(~'C' + 1)`) will give us the original number - just with the LSB not set anymore, because it was set before the final inversion (which inverted the LSB like every other bit).

Answer (score 0):

it's same as above let e simplify

- **'C'** in decimal is 67 and in binary as 01000011
- ('C'***-1**) in decimal is -67 and in binary we have to take compliment of 67
  and add 1 to its compliment = 10111100 +1 = *10111101*
- **~**('C'*-1) is negation of -67 i.e compliment of *10111101* is
  01000010 which in decimal is 66 in ascii is 'B'